# c# backgroundWorker not raising ProgressChanged or RunWorkerCompleted events

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5, backgroundworker

Using C# .NET 3.5.

It seems I'm not the only one, since a search seems to bring up a lot of similar questions, however reading through them I seem still to be missing the solution.

I'm raising an event with a button click on my UI, which is then supposed to start a backgroundWorker to get some time consuming work done - in this case, I want it to collect information from a form and a) write to an xml file as well as b) insert the information into a remote database.

This is exactly what the backgroundWorker was designed and intended to do I believe.

Here is the event raising code.

```
private void btnFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clkFinish.setInstant();
    curAct.setTimeFinish(DateTime.Now);
    btnStart.Enabled = true;
    bgwDataWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread a: " + i);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        if (i == (20 - 1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        }
    }
    
}
```

As you can see, I have some code there which I've used as a counterbalance to the background worker code, which is here:

```
private void bgwDataWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running in a different thread now");
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread b: " + i);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(5 * i, null);
        if (i == (21 - 1))
        {
            count = i;
        }
    }
    e.Result = count;
}
```

So far, everything seems to be working up to this point.

My problem is that when the code in the DoWork method is finished, nothing is happening. Here are the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerComplete methods.

```
private void bgwDataWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage);
}

private void bgwDataWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Result is " + e.Result.ToString());
    
}
```

This has me baffled.

I've tried running the [examples from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and I'm experiencing the same problems. RunWorkerCompleted and ReportProgress events are simply not being raised for some reason and I don't understand why.

Thanks for reading.

Alan

Comment: You are using a background worker in a console app, correct? Are you seeing any console ouput? This looks more like windows app because you have a button click event handler at the top. Do you have a console window when you run the app?

Comment: Jodrell, thanks. No, this isn't a console app, its a windows form based application. I'm using Visual Studio 10, the console.writeline output is coming from the debug output.

Comment: @inksmithy: I'm seeing the same behaviour - did you ever get it solved?

Comment: @BlueChippy unfortunately, no, I ended up throwing everything into a timer. Not an ideal solution, but since the timer uses its own thread to run its task, it got the job done. I'm still trying to find the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and I just figured out the answer.

In the properties of the backgroundworker, make sure that ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted list the **name** of their functions (mine are called 'backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged' and 'backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted' respectively).

Answer (score 5):

You didn´t miss to set these variables, did you?

```
backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
```

Also it could be an exception in the DoWork-Method, that isn´t handled.

Comment: Sanz, thanks for the reply. I've used the visual editor in visual studio 2010 and dragged the backgroundWorker onto the form, then adjusted both of those properties to "true" in the properties pane. I have renamed the backgroundWorker though, could that have an impact? Also, I'm not seeing any exceptions in the debug output, I'm simply seeing work stop.

Comment: I would try it with a clear DoWork-Method then, perhaps just one Console.WriteLine call and see if it then works.

Comment: I've edited the DoWork method to this:
private void bgwDataWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Resting again, 1 sec");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            String fin = "finished now";
            e.Result = fin;
        } and I've changed the RunWorkerCompleted method to this:   private void bgwDataWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Result is " + (String)e.Result);
        }

Comment: Minimarkdown failing on me, I'm sorry. The result is, no change in the behaviour. I dont understand this, my environment is Windows 7 Ultimate, I'm running on a new, quad core processor. with plenty of memory.

Answer (score 3):

Inksmithy, you mentioned you have renamed the BackgroundWorker. Please note that when you do this, the Forms Designer does NOT automatically change the reference to the old DoWork and RunWorkerCompleted methods. So in your Forms designer, click on your BackgroundWorker, then click on the Events icon (lightning bolt) in the Properties Window, and double-check that it is pointing to the correct Event Method Names.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I had checked it, but I didn't mention it on the initial question. Its a good point though, its very easy to miss.

Comment: I had the same problem as the op.  Even though I didn't change the name of my background worker, the background workers properties did not have the event method names set.  By doing what Heliac suggested, solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Set `WorkerReportsProgress` property to True.

Comment: thanks for the reply, that flag has been set on the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You've left out a vital bit - a boolean flag to allow it to raise the events

```
bgwDataWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
bgwDataWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes, both those flags have been set.

Answer (score 0):

I had one project [A], (built a while back) that had the progress bar working. The current app [B] is not reporting progress. For some reason app [A] had the progress and work completed event handlers wired up. So, I hooked up the event handlers in app [B] and it is working. The handlers are copied into the designer.cs partial class file. (Assuming they could go in the form.cs partial class).

```
// 
        // backgroundWorker1
        // 
        this.backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        this.backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        this.backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
        this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
//
```

hope this helps. Don't know why the app [A] was wired up by using the toolbox to drop the background worker on the form design window. Using VS2012 and Windows 7.

Also, I am calculating the progress percentage and for some reason the number of items in the listbox times the number of selected checkboxes exceeded 100% - it threw and error. So, I will cap the percentage at 99 and make that part of my logic for the progress percentage being reported back to the event.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently. It was caused because I had the main thread sleeping until the background thread was finished, which blocked the update from executing.

I solved this by wrapping my object (containing worker threads) into another thread so the progress update could execute, change the values in the main thread allowing my sleeping thread to continue.